# psgo.sty the goboards are not drawn

Tags: diagrams, pstricks

I use TeXlive on Debian Wheezy. I have `psgo.sty` installed (in `texlive-games`).
I have downloaded `psgomanual.tex`.

After I enter the command `latex psgomanual.tex` I get a `.dvi` file. With lots of warnings of the form:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 345--346
[]|\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 \stone[\markma]\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 f\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 black\OMS
/cmsy/m/n/10 gf\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 b\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 gf\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 2\OMS/cmsy
/m/n/10 g
```

The writing's in the `.dvi` file are all ok, but instead of the Go board diagrams there is something like the image below. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Could you submit the minimal working example of your code?

Comment: @christoph. thanks. it works. I thought there is some serious problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of the two most frequent errors done with PSTricks packages. If you use PSTricks (*Postscript* Tricks), you cannot view the `dvi` output, but must look at the `ps` or `pdf` output. To generate the output, there are several ways, which one you use depends on your workflow, packages etc.:

- `latex` -> `dvips` (-> `ps2pdf`)
- `xelatex`
- `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` and then `pdflatex -shell-escape`
- Several other ways, see e.g. http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Answer (score 0):

Run the document with `xelatex`, it does the conversion process automatically.